# Can I try and catch exceptions in setters if so how do I do it correctly?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods, getter, setter

What i want to happen is to have the user input the age and have the program use the getters and setters while also checking for exceptions and if it does catch an exception it would have to run through the method again.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    TestPatient patientZero = new TestPatient();
    patientZero.setAge(in.nextInt());
    System.out.println(patientZero.getAge());

}

}
```

//
Patient class

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPatient {
private int age;

```
public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int newAge){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter in Your age:");
            age = in.nextInt();
            success = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Im sorry, please enter just you age.\nTry again");
        }
    this.age=newAge;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand why you're passing `newAge` into `setAge()` and then prompting the user to enter an age, which isn't used.

Comment: Don't mix user interface (UI) code with data structural classes (e.g., the Patient class). They should be completely separate

Answer (score 1):

Your overall program structure could be improved as you're mixing your data structural code, e.g., the Patient class, with your I/O code, e.g., the Scanner input code. These should be completely separate, something like:

```
public class TestPatient { 
    private int age;

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        this.age = newAge;
    }

}
```

Then I/O can go elsewhere:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // get your data here and create your new TestPatient
    
}
```

Why is this important? You don't know in advance how you will eventually use your main code, and need to keep it open and flexible to be used in any I/O situation, including GUI if need be.

Also, your code will create a new Scanner object for each setter call, and that is a dangerous thing to do, since if a Scanner based on System.in is closed, then the program no longer can get input from the user.

Note also that it is OK to throw an exception from a setter method if the data being passed in is not allowed.

e.g.,

```
    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        if (newAge <= 0) {
            String text = "for newAge is less than or equal to 0: " + newAge;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
        }
        this.age = newAge;
    }
```

Comment: So to clarify what you are saying: in the main class get the data and after that create my new patients as needed?

Comment: @zackeryTarantino: perhaps in the main class, or in a separate I/O class, but either way, it should be separate from your structural classes. No sense painting yourself into a corner unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop. You also don't need the `newAge` parameter, as you are reading user input.

```
public void setAge(){
    int age;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean success = false;
    while (!success) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter in Your age:");
            age = in.nextInt();
            success = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            success = false;
            System.out.println("Im sorry, please enter just you age.\nTry again");
        }
    }
    this.age=age;
}
```